# Using select-string to find 2 strings in the same document

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell command to search files that contain BOTH strings input by the user.  Right now I can search for the one string, but can not figure out how to make sure that it has both strings.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am searching in a local directory that stores a bunch of .SQL files.  The file path is input by the user (C:\Program Files\Common Files), Then the first string is input by the user, and last the second string.  I need the script to search thru all the files and only display the files with both strings in the document.

```
#Requests the loctation of the files to search
$Location = Read-Host 'What is the folder location of the files you want to search?'

#Sets the location based off of the above variable
Set-Location $Location 

#Sets the alias
Set-Alias ss Select-String 

#Requests the text to search for in the files
$File_Name = Read-Host 'Object Name?'
$File_Name2 = Read-Host 'Second Object Name'

#Searches the files and returns the filenames
Get-ChildItem -r | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | ss -Pattern '($File_Name|$File_Name2)'  | Format-List FileName
```

Comment: What do the contents of the `$Location` folder look like? What kind of data are you searching inside of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you. Check out the in-line comments.

```
# 1. Let's assume the folder c:\test contains a bunch of plain text files
#    and we want to find only the ones containing 'foo' AND 'bar'
$ItemList = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test -Filter *.txt -Recurse;

# 2. Define the search terms
$Search1 = 'foo';
$Search2 = 'bar';

# 3. For each item returned in step 1, check to see if it matches both strings
foreach ($Item in $ItemList) {
    $Content = $null = Get-Content -Path $Item.FullName -Raw;
    if ($Content -match $Search1 -and $Content -match $Search2) {
        Write-Host -Object ('File ({0}) matched both search terms' -f $Item.FullName);
    }
}
```

After creating several test files, my output looks like the following:

```
File (C:\test\test1.txt) matched both search terms
```

Comment: Since those search terms are going to be user entered input I'd run them through [regex]::escape() before using them as -match arguments.

Answer (score 5):

A perhaps more simple approach is to just use `Select-String` twice:

```
$filename1 = [regex]::escape($File_Name)
$filename2 = [regex]::escape($File_Name2)
Get-ChildItem -r | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Select-String $filename1 | 
    Select-String $filename2
```

Answer (score 2):

Trevor Sullivan's solution looks good to me, but if you wanted a pure regex way of doing this, you would use the following string:

`string1(?=string2)|string2(?=string1)`

Which basically says,

> Try to find string1 and string2 after it somewhere,
>
> otherwise try to look for string2 and string1 after it somewhere.

You'd need to search the whole file raw, not line by line, for this to work.